# Some Salesforce Hiccups

Tags: custom-field, calendar, address, quota

I'm currently building out a salesforce instance and was surprised that there isn't a way to create a custom address field. Does anyone have any experience working around this other than creating a bunch of individual fields and linking them together with a formula field?

I am also curious if anyone has attempted to create a view that shows all sales events on one calendar by each sales person so that schedulers and management can see an overview of how booked people are or what openings they have?

I was also trying to create quotas for sales persons however my company has sales budgets fragmented by what division they are. These divisions are broken by opportunity record type. However many salespersons have multiples quotas spanning different divisions, would there be a way to create a quota for each record type?

Thanks for any help or possible suggestions for some of these roadblocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm currently building out a salesforce instance and was surprised that there isn't a way to create a custom address field. Does anyone have any experience working around this other than creating a bunch of individual fields and linking them together with a formula field?

Not right now, but it's [in development](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrVWAA0) (Safe Harbor: no idea when or if this will actually happen).

> I am also curious if anyone has attempted to create a view that shows all sales events on one calendar by each sales person so that schedulers and management can see an overview of how booked people are or what openings they have?

Yes, you can do this by going to the Home tab, clicking on Multi-User view, and then navigating the calendar. Users can create filters (list views) to select just the users they would like to display. There is no Lightning equivalent of this, as far as I can tell, but will probably be available in some future release.

> I was also trying to create quotas for sales persons however my company has sales budgets fragmented by what division they are. These divisions are broken by opportunity record type. However many salespersons have multiples quotas spanning different divisions, would there be a way to create a quota for each record type?

Not by record type. You can forecast by Product Family, though. If you create multiple product families, you can specify a forecast for each family. See Setup > Customize > Forecasts (Customizable) > Forecast Settings. You could also use Territory Management, but that has some pretty serious implications (which is why it requires a technical support case to enable), but you can try it out in a sandbox/developer org first if you're interested in forecasting by territory.